# Scaling down the PNG images is increasing the image size

Tags: python, algorithm, png, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I am trying to scale down all the images in a folder to 90% of their respective sizes. Wrote this :

```
from PIL import Image
import sys, csv, os, traceback

path = "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Textures\\"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
scalingFactor = .9

def resize():
 for item in dirs:
    print 'item', path+item
    if os.path.isfile(path+item):
        im = Image.open(path+item)
        f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
        imResize = im.resize((int(im.size[0]*scalingFactor),int(im.size[1]*scalingFactor)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        fileName = f.split('\\')[-1]
        imResize.save(path + "/Out/" + fileName + ' resized_' + str(scalingFactor) + ".png" , 'PNG')
```

However, when I run it, the size of images are actually increasing instead of decreasing (as I expect).

eg. Original Image 885x1130 466KB

[image]

Output Image 796x1017 1.44 MB!

[image]

I have had a rather similar un-intuitive experience earlier with PNGs while rotating them and got an [explanation about it here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786313/rotating-image-increases-its-size). But I can't convinve myself that this is perhaps the same issue.

Any clues ? and something else I can do to reduce the PNG size ? Am ok with a little loss in quality if required.

Comment: Are you scaling these images down because you want the smaller pixel size? Or are you doing it in an attempt to reduce the byte size of the files?

Comment: Note that scaling with anti-aliasing can create a _lot_ of intermediate colours that aren't present in the original, and that can alter the compressibility of the image. PNG has many compression options, but few programs give you access to the parameters that allow you to "tune" the compression, and selecting the best parameters is a complex task. There are a few PNG re-compression programs floating around; I use & recommend [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net).

Comment: @PM2Ring I want smaller file size. And yes I am using OptiPNG as a part of post processing but it wasn't reducing the size to the point I wanted. So I thought of scaling it down and expected a reduction in file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `Image.ANTIALIAS` filter which is a high-quality downsampling filter.

To reduce the size of the image you can use `optimize=True` and `quality=90` while saving the image. Like -

```
imResize.save(path + "/Out/" + fileName + ' resized_' + str(scalingFactor) + ".png" ,optimize=True,quality=90)
```

The optimize flag will do an extra pass on the image to find a way to reduce it's size as much as possible.

Now to reduce the size further, you can change the quality value in the save options.

I prefer quality 85 with `optimize` because the quality isn't affected much, and the file size is much smaller.

Hope this helps!

---

Just to add to your answer, all the filters are listed here to make a decision about quality vs speed of execution etc.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#filters

Comment: Thanks @amit. Great help !!